# Meteor: REST collection API and auth

Tags: rest, authentication, meteor

In the need to expose part of my Meteor collections through REST, I stumbled across a the [Collection API Meteorite package](https://github.com/crazytoad/meteor-collectionapi).

Whereas this indeed makes it possible to expose a Meteor Collection through REST, it does not take any security into account. Is there any way I can integrate the Collection API with the Meteor auth system introduced in `0.5.2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, kinda. Using the REST meteorite package, you can declare your collection and then use the [allow](http://docs.meteor.com/#allow) rules on the collection, but with a couple caveats (**NOTE:** this is pseudo-code that requires more work!):

```
Players = new Meteor.Collection("players");

//a collection of associated userids and auth token headers
APIUsers = new Meteor.Collection("apiusers"); 

Players.allow({
    insert: function (userId, doc) {
        //invoking this from a RESTful context means the userId is NOT 
        //available, so you'll need to do three things things: 
        //    (1) a way to get the current http request's X-Auth-Token header
        //    (2) a collection to look up the user(s) associated with 
        //        that token
        //    (3) and an owner field on the Players collection to join back 
        //        to the found userids.
        return (_.indexOf(APIUsers.findOne(
                    {XAuthToken: __CURRENT_X_AUTH_TOKEN__}).users
                 , doc.owner) > -1;
    },
    update: function (userId, docs, fields, modifier) {
       /* similar logic */
    },
    remove: function (userId, docs) {
       /* similar logic */
    },
    fetch: ['owner']
});
```

**BUT** while I think the RESTful approach will prove useful in integrating legacy applications into a Meteor context, I would highly recommend looking into the [DDP protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128430/documentation-or-code-details-on-meteors-ddp-pub-sub-protocol/13736614#13736614) for integration of new projects.

As you can see above, the [allow](http://docs.meteor.com/#allow) rules do not expose a GET callback, presumably because the expectation is the GET is defined in the publication the server exposes. A DDP client is wired at a lower level to subscribe to these publications, so GETs in this context will be much more granular than a RESTful approach.

Comment: seems as if the right way is to wait for the official REST endpoint support by the Meteor team ;(

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stumbling across this now, [Restivus](https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus) allows you to generate REST endpoints on collections, and configure user authentication and role permissions on those endpoints. The default authentication uses Meteor's built-in login token mechanism to authenticate a `Meteor.user` and provide access to `this.user` and `this.userId` in authenticated endpoints. You can also provide a custom authentication method if the default is too much, or not enough, for you. Here's a quick example (hope you can read CoffeeScript):

```
# Generates: GET, POST on /api/users and GET, DELETE on /api/users/:id for
# Meteor.users collection
Restivus.addCollection Meteor.users
  excludedEndpoints: ['deleteAll', 'put']
  routeOptions:
    authRequired: true
  endpoints:
    post:
      authRequired: false
    delete:
      roleRequired: 'admin'
```